# Elasticsearch match names with a comma

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble searching for names that contain a comma. For example, searching 'John Smith' does not return 'Smith, John'.

My name field is indexed as a textfield, and my search query looks like this:

```
s = s.query("multi_match", query=query, type='phrase', phrase_slop=1, fields=['name', 'title'])
```

I added the phrase_slop=1 to successfully match names like 'John D Smith' when searching 'John Smith'. But how can I modify my query to match names with a comma?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_value_fields.html) is from elasticsearch reference. It might help. This kind of issue typically has to do with how the analyzer is set when creating the index.  I recommend testing your index settings and queries in a console [UI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.0/console-kibana.html).